# How to print the user input in python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

How to print the below line in python 3.x in below format.

```
print ("How old are you?"),
age = input ()
print ("How tall are you ?"),
height = input ()
print ("How much do you weigh?"),
weight = input()

print("so , you're % year old, % ft tall and % kg heavy.")% (age,height,weight)
```

## Error:-

```
How old are you?
35
How tall are you ?
2
How much do you weigh?
23
```

so , you're %x year old, %x ft tall and %x kg heavy.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Narendra/8th July Ethans
>   Python Batch/Exercises/Python3/ex11.py", line 8, in 
>       print("so , you're %x year old, %x ft tall and %x kg heavy.")% (age,height,weight) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %:
>   'NoneType' and 'tuple'

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Python >= 3.6: Use `f-string`

**Ex:**

```
age = input ("How old are you?\n");

height = input ("How tall are you ?\n");

weight = input("How much do you weigh?\n");

print(f"so , you're {age} year old, {height} ft tall and {weight} kg heavy.")
```

or `str.format`

**Ex:**

```
print("so , you're {0} year old, {1} ft tall and {2} kg heavy.".format(age, height, weight))
```

Answer (score 2):

The format operator `%` works on a string, not on the entire `print` function, which always returns `None`. Also, you need to specify the format of the placeholders with specifications such as `%s`.

```
print("so , you're %s year old, %s ft tall and %s kg heavy." % (age,height,weight))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the .format() function like this;

```
age = input('How old are you? ')
height = input('How tall are you? ' )
weight = input('How much do you weigh? ')

print(("so, you're {} year old, {} ft tall and {} kg heavy").format(age,height,weight))
```

Comment: working perfect:  How old are you?
23
How tall are you ?
3
How much do you weigh?
45
so, you're 23 year old, 3 ft tall and 45 kg heavy